# CodenameOne BrowserComponent not working on UWP build

Tags: java, uwp, codenameone

We have a CodenameOne app that uses `BrowserComponent` (added to a Form) to load our SPA webapp after splash screen, on Android device it works fine. Now we want to submit to windows store, during testing on Windows 10 PC and Mobile phone the app install successfully but when I run the app, after splash screen the next form shows blank. The `BrowserComponent` added to form has 2 web event listeners `onLoad` and `onError` none triggers when the form containing the component shows.

The Laptop and Mobile Phone for testing have Internet access.

Comment: I didn't understand if this works on the simulator and fails on the device and if so which devices. Does it work on any device? How does the browser component code look. Is the onLoad/onError written in Java? What's in those methods?

Comment: Is the onLoad/onError written in Java? Yes.

It works on simulator and failed on Windows 10 PC and Window 10 Phone.

Comment: Does it work on other devices and only fails on the UWP port?
What's the code that you used?